# eci to ecef coordinates transformation

Tags: c++, latitude-longitude, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation, satellite

I am a newbie in space mechanics and coordinates transformation. I need to transform from earth-centered-intertial system coordinates to earth-centered-earth-fixed(ECEF or ECR). I found the library SConvert.

[SConvert library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sconvert/)

In function `makeEciToEcrMatrix`, who create Euler matrix, we have first argument as time*earth angular velocity(rad/sec). And my question: what is the time? What is its value? Is it number of seconds from 1 jan 1970, or 1 jan 2000, or something else?

Comment: When you have one moving and one stationary frame, time is from when they are equal.

Comment: sorry, but i don't understand you... tell more please

Answer (score 1):

In orbital mechanics the orbit solution is generating by integrating Equations of Motion of a satellite. That integration is done in inertial coordinate system (ECI). To make the orbit solution more useful and user friendly, it is usually transformed to Earth fixed coordinate system (EFEC). To do that you need Earth Perturbation, Nutation, Earth Rotation, and Polar motion information. All those information requires the time as input parameter. The time is usually atomic clock based time system. Usually unix time system based on 1 Jan, 1970 is not used. It can be 1 Jan, 2000. (For example at NASA J2K time scale is widely used.) But it can be other time scale, but it has to be eventually transformed to the proper time scale where each earth rotation information (Precession, Nutation, Rotation, Polar Motion) is formulated or tabulated.

Anyhow, in your case, if you already have ECI orbit solution, that means you have ti, Xi, Yi, Zi, Ui, Vi, Wi at each time epoch. You can provide the same ti for coordinate system transformation. The proper time conversion should be done inside of the function you are calling.